# Pandas "mean" of boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I am really confused, why just False as a result is displayed and not like 0.8 because there is 4 true and 1 false for column 3 (Value3). I read that it should be possible with mean, but I can not solve it

Maybe someone can give me a little hint what I do wrong?

```
data = [
    {
    "Datum": "2019-05-11",
    "Value1": True,
    "Value2": 10,
    "Value3": False,
    "Value4": 20
    },
    {
    "Datum": "2019-05-11",
    "Value1": True,
    "Value2": 20,
    "Value3": True,
    "Value4": 40
    },  
    {
    "Datum": "2019-05-11",
    "Value1": True,
    "Value2": 20,
    "Value3": True,
    "Value4": 40
    },     
    {
    "Datum": "2019-05-11",
    "Value1": True,
    "Value2": 10,
    "Value3": True,
    "Value4": 20
    },
    {
    "Datum": "2019-05-11",
    "Value1": True,
    "Value2": 20,
    "Value3": True,
    "Value4": 40
    },      
    {
    "Datum": "2019-05-12",
    "Value1": True,
    "Value2": 30,
    "Value3": True,
    "Value4": 50
    },
    {
    "Datum": "2019-05-12",
    "Value1": True,
    "Value2": 40,
    "Value3": True,
    "Value4": 60
    }
] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
ordered_df = df.groupby("Datum").agg("mean")
```

the result is:

```
ordered_df["Value3"]
Datum
2019-05-11    False
Name: Value3, dtype: bool
```

I expect sth like this:

```
Datum
2019-05-11    0.8
2019-05-12    1.0
Name: Value3, dtype: float64
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**
Can someone please try it with this data?

And than I do the DataFrame and groupby stuff...still dont mean the bool values

```
input_data = data["data"]
df = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
ordered_df = df.groupby("Datum").agg("mean")
ordered_df["Notabschaltung"]
```

Still the same

```
Datum
2019-11-12    False
Name: Notabschaltung, dtype: bool
```

Comment: When I ran the program I got same output as in your expected output!

Comment: I am not getting your errant result when I run your posted code.

Comment: I get exactly what you expect if I copy&paste your code into my Python 3.6 environment. What are your Python and Pandas versions?

Comment: Same here using Python 2.7. I get your expected output. You wrongly copy-pasted something in your code I guess

Comment: I added some other data...I dont know why it isnt working. I use jupyter in a python 3.7 env

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the second example I indeed get False.

To overcome this you can use:

```
df["Notabschaltung"] = df["Notabschaltung"]*1
```

This **will convert True to 1 and False to 0 and then**

```
ordered_df = df.groupby("Datum").agg("mean")
ordered_df["Notabschaltung"]
```

> Datum
>
> 2019-11-12    0.0
>
> Name: Notabschaltung, dtype: int64

Comment: Neat trick to convert to 0/1